# How do I generate a printable only link for 3D Printers rather downloadable link for the model?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, printing

I am doing a project for a company which sells their 3D printable models (.STL) online. The company wants to add some specific models into their digital inventory but doesn’t want to let someone download it. Rather, once a customer pays for the model, the customer should be able to print the model straightaway onto their 3D printer (assuming the customer has already got a 3D printer which is set to print). 
Once the payment made for the model, the system should be able to give the access to the customer to print on their own 3D printing machine. The purpose of this access for the direct print on the 3D printer is to restrict the number of models customer can print. So, for example, if a customer pays for a model to make 1 x print he should be able to only get one print.
Any thoughts on this process scholarly-wise as well as programming wise considering work need to be done using Laravel and Vue js. Any sort of example already done or any tutorial link would be much appreciate!

Comment: How can a model travel from your site to a client's 3d printer without somehow being transferred over the wire? And if it is transferred over the wire wouldn't someone simply be able to capture it before it's sent to the printer?

Comment: Thanks for you input. Locks to the door are normally for those who aren't thieves. Thieves breaking in. Anyway, considerable point but assuming they are not capturing it before it's sent to the printer! My question is wether it's possible or not? And the one who voted negative, could you please show or direct towards some research work done on this topic or is it just your limited research?

Comment: Assuming they wont capture it then the simple thing to do is generate a random URL for the printable page which will only work once and when the user accesses it, it is no longer accessible. Personally I think the major concern should be re-distribution. Someone saving the model should be ok because all sorts of things can happen like there's a sudden power failure mid-print and you wouldn't want to force people through hoops if that happens. Protection from re-distribution is usually done using legal safeguards

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for your time and effort! This could be a good start https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/15604-inside-the-ultimaker-3-day-3-remote-access-part-2/?tab=comments#comment-224912  .... . Also http://<IP_OF_YOUR_PRINTER>/cluster-api/v1/print_jobs/
(where <IP_OF_YOUR_PRINTER> is the IP address of a Cura Connect group host) this can help as this is the BIBLE for the web api (Ultimaker)

Answer (score 0):

Well. This is a fairly a new topic and all I wanted was a brainstorming sort of discussion. Can't understand why someone put it as a FLAG Down, but never mind!
I have found a solution exactly what I was looking for. And the rest of you who find the similar or same problem for the 3d printing, slicing or GCODE you can refer here.

3dPrinterOS is a cloud based management tool which provide you with the functionality to restrict a customer with only to print a GCODE (without downloading it) as well restrict the number of prints.
So, here is the link below:
https://cloud.3dprinteros.com/
They have free version which is full of juice so make the most of it!

P.S. The only thing is that you are not providing the .STL file to the customers rather it would be GCODE file, coz if you provide STL file they can slice it more than once and prints as well.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/15604-inside-the-ultimaker-3-day-3-remote-access-part-2/?tab=comments#comment-224912  .... .

Also,
http://IP_OF_YOUR_PRINTER/cluster-api/v1/print_jobs/
(where **IP_OF_YOUR_PRINTER** is the IP address of a Cura Connect group host)

This is the BIBLE for the web api (Ultimaker)

You might need to replace the single quotes into double as I had to on Windows, once you playing with the Swagger UI and running commands at command prompt as well.